# Private page accessible to admin only, other logged in users get 404

Tags: wordpress

I have a private page on my website, accessible only to logged in editor users. When I log in as admin, I can see the page without problems, however, when someone else logs in (Editors), they get a 404.

To be exact, they get what you get when you run single.php and the condition `<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` is false.

How could I possibly diagnose this? Even with debug turned on, I get no further messages and am quite clueless as to what could be causing this. I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: In WordPress, by default, the "Editor" role does not have the capability to access private pages unless they are the author of those pages. Editors can typically only access and edit content that has been published or assigned to them.